# Is copying a collection before iteration enough to prevent synchronization problems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, synchronization

I have a `sessions` property, a mutable set. I need to iterate over the collection, but at the same time I could change the collection in another method:

```
- (Session*) sessionWithID: (NSString*) sessionID
{
    for (Session *candidate in _sessions) {
        /* do something */
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) doSomethingElse
{
    [_sessions removeObject:…];
}
```

This isn’t thread-safe. A bullet-proof version would be using `@synchronized` or a dispatch queue to serialize the `_sessions` access. But how reasonable is to simply copy the set before iterating over it?

```
- (Session*) sessionWithID: (NSString*) sessionID
{
    for (Session *candidate in [_sessions copy]) {
        /* do something */
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I don’t care about the performance difference much.

Comment: Seems it pretty usual approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how reasonable is to simply copy the set before iterating over it?

As presented, it is not guaranteed to be thread safe. You would need to guarantee that `_sessions` is not mutated during `-copy`. Then iterating over an immutable copy is safe, and mutation of `_sessions` may occur on a secondary thread or in your implementation.

In many cases with Cocoa collections, you will find it is preferable to use immutable ivars and *copy on set* by declaring the property as `copy` of type `NSSet`. This way, you copy on write/set, and then avoid the copy on read. This has the potential to reduce copies, depending on how your program actually executes. Generally, this alone is not enough, and you will need some higher level of synchronization.

Also remember that the `Session`s in the set may not be thread safe. Even once your collections accesses are properly guarded, you may need to protect access to those objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not look thread-safe to me because the collection might be mutated from another thread *while it is copied*.

You would have to protect `[_sessions copy]` and `[_sessions removeObject:…]` from
executing simultaneously.

After creating the copy, you can iterate over it without a lock (assuming that the collection elements themselves are not modified from another thread).

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I have a background simulation that a GLView is drawn based on.  In order to do the drawing in a background thread I need to copy the simulation's current frame data, then perform the drawing based on that data so that the simulation can continue in it's own thread and not distort the drawing data.

I see the copying of information to be used asynchronously as perfectly valid.  Especially in devices that have multiple cores.  `@synchronize` causes the separate threads to stop (if they are accessing the same information) and thereby can cause more of a performance loss than the copy procedure.